# Why am I unable to open my DVD drive?

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have Windows 7 64bit installed on my laptop and a few months ago my DVD drive was working, but now, when I try to use it, it does not work. The disk drive will open and close, but when it tried to read a DVD nothing happens. The system keeps acting like it's trying to read it, then stops, then starts again

I've also checked it in Device Manager and I don't see any yellow exclamation mark, which means the system is able to detect/recognize this drive properly.

What could be the reason and how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you can't open the tray or the contents of the disc in the drive?

Comment: I am also confused if you mean physically open the tray or simply read the contents to the disk.

Comment: Also, does this consistently happen with any media you try using?

Comment: Yes, Happening consistently with different media. and using Laptop.

Comment: This is typical of the behavior if the drive's optics are dirty.  You can have a shot at using a drive cleaning CD.  You can also get this behavior if the hub isn't grasping the CD properly.  Check your CDs to be sure there's no "flash", etc on the center hole.

Comment: is this happening with a few discs or all of discs that you put in?

i mean, sometimes some discs are unreadable.

Comment: @tumchaaditya: i tried different discs... none of them worked...

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is going on here:

1. **It's a hardware failure.** As Oliver asked you, can you open the drive tray? If not, the drive itself may either be broken or disconnected from the computer. If it's a desktop computer, check the cables and make sure they're seated properly. It's also possible that the laser on the drive has gone out or the lens is dirty. Either of those two will cause the drive to malfunction.
2. **It's a failure within Windows.** If you haven't already tried it, attempt to boot the computer from the DVD drive (once you've tried checking the hardware itself). You can use a Linux Live CD, or better yet, the Windows 7 install disk or recovery media (if you have it). If that works, you have a problem within Windows.

In the event that it's a hardware failure, It's possible you can buy a CD/DVD lens cleaner (basically a disk with a really fine brush on the bottom of it), but I haven't seen one of those in years. If it's a laptop and it's out of warranty, you're really better off getting an external USB drive to replace it. Otherwise, contact the laptop's manufacturer--something like this should be covered under warranty.

Comment: in case its lens is not working properly, how can i fix this issue myself?

Comment: I edited my answer.